# Auto refreshing page with saved input

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, input

I'm trying to make a JSP that refresh itself every 2scd approximately and keep what the user tip in input form.

My idea was to save the input with javascript, add them to the URL and refresh the page, then retrieve and set the input.

This is my JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

function refreshPage(){

```
  var mapValue = new Array();
  var mapName = new Array();
  var i = 0;
  $(".positionInput").each(function() {
      mapValue[i] = $(this).val();
      mapName[i] = $(this).attr("name");
      i++;
  });

  var parameters = "";

  for(i = 0; i < mapName.length; i++){
     if(mapValue[i] != ""){
        parameters += "?" + mapName[i] + "=" + mapValue[i];
     }
  }

  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/drawinguess/waitingplayer.jsp" + parameters;

  setTimeout(refreshPage, 2000);  //execute itself every 2s
```

}

refreshPage();

});

But the timer get crazy (even with 1mn delay), it refresh itself as fast as he can with window.location.href (without this, it's working fine)

Thanks in advance if you have any other idea or if I'm making something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and use local storage for this. The best way would be that instead of refreshing the entire page, you only refresh what is needed by having services set up and using an async function like fetch() to hit those services and update the page.

Comment: I konw what you mean I'll try
The solution was to put setTimeout(refreshPage, 2000); before the function and delete refreshPage();